# Make getElementsByClassName differ between 2 classes with the same name

Tags: javascript, html, class

I got a HTML page with two div/class elements with the same name, called "notifications". However, I want to count only the latter ones and dont count the  first one.

The first one looks like this:

```
<a href="mynotifcations"><div class="notification">1</div>
```

This one should be excluded.

The later ones look like this:

```
<div class="notiheader"><span class="notification">2 notifications</span>
```

Right now I get the notification like this

```
document.getElementsByClassName("notification");
```

If I cycle through it, it returns "1" and then "2 notifications".

I would rather get merely the "2 notifications", or better yet just the number 2 as an integer.

How do I manage to do achieve that? I'm really running out of ideas :/

Comment: Simple solution, can you update it to add a class that does nothing? Is there a common parent around the ones you care about? Is there a pattern with the one that you care about that does not match the other. Details are needed.

Comment: `parseInt(document.getElementsByClasName('notification')[1], 10)`

Comment: or, just give them different ids and use  `getElementById('someid')`

Comment: Unfortunately the HTML page is external, I can't do anything with that and need to work with what I got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have to say that is a strange setup, but here is a way:

```
<script>
var special = document.querySelectorAll( "span.notification" );
alert (special[1].innerHTML);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to add a class to distinguish them (that's what they're for), but if you must, you can use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to match the specific ones you're looking for:

```
document.querySelectorAll("div .notification")
```

This will only match `div`s with the `notification` class.

```js
var elementsWanted = document.querySelectorAll("div .notification");

for(var i = 0; i < elementsWanted.length; i++){
    elementsWanted[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

```html
<div class="notification">Span</div>
<div class="notiheader"><span class="notification">Div</span>
<div class="notiheader"><span class="notification">Div</span>
<div class="notiheader"><span class="notification">Div</span>
<div class="notiheader"><span class="notification">Div</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, here we first get all the `notification` classes, `x.length` gives the total no of `notification` classes in the html. Then do your stuff based on its index(zero based index).

```
   function hookSecondNotification() {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("notification")[1];
        // x.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        // here do your stuffs.
    }
```

Comment: Why a loop if you're only interested in a single index?

Comment: My previous answer useful when you want to hook the multiple elements based on its index.